# EasyPermissions problem with requestPermissions Android/Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have error with EasyPermissions.requestPermissions
Thats my error:

"None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun requestPermissions(host: Activity, rationale: String, requestCode: Int, vararg perms: String!): Unit defined in pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions
public open fun requestPermissions(host: Fragment, rationale: String, requestCode: Int, vararg perms: String!): Unit defined in pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions"

```
@HiltViewModel class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

    private fun requestPermissions(context: Context) {
        if(TrackingUtility.hasLocationPermissions(context)) {
            return
        }
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                host = this,
                rationale = "You need to accept location permissions to use this app.",
                requestCode = REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )

        } else {
            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val permissions = PermissionRequest.Builder(
                host,
                0,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ).build()

            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(permissions)
```

I did it like this, but I'm not sure if it's a good solution